# Error: Call to a member function cipher() on null

Tags: php

I keep getting the same error whenever I test my code. I am using PHP 7.2. Some syntax is for 7.2 so it may look different. I keep getting the error below.

> Error: Call to a member function cipher() on null

```
<?php

namespace Genial\Cryptography\Password;

use \Genial\Cryptography\
{
    Utils,
    Exception\RangeException,
    Exception\LengthException
};

/**
 * Bcrypt.
 */
class Bcrypt extends AbstractPasswordHash
{

    /**
     * @var int $cost The cost `Bcrypt` should use during execution.
     */
    private $cost = 10;

    /**
     * __construct().
     *
     * Set the available options for `Bcrypt` hashing.
     *
     * The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0.
     *
     * @param int $cost The cost `Bcrypt` should use during execution.
     *
     * @return void.
     */
    function __construct(int $cost)
    {
        if ($cost < 2)
        {
            throw new RangeException(\sprintf(
                '`%s` The cost passed is too low. Passed: `%s`.',
                __METHOD__,
                \htmlspecialchars($cost, \ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
            ));
        }
        $this->cost = $cost;
    }

    /**
     * getCost().
     *
     * Get the current cost set.
     *
     * @return int Returns the current cost set.
     */
    public function getCost()
    {
        return $this->cost;
    }

    /**
     * cipher().
     *
     * Hash the plaintext using `Bcrypt`.
     *
     * @param string $plaintext The plaintext to hash during execution.
     *
     * @return string Returns the plaintext hashed using `Bcrypt`.
     */
    public function cipher(string $plaintext): string
    {
        if (\mb_strlen($plaintext) > 72)
        {
            throw new LengthException(\sprintf(
                '`%s` The password is longer than 72 characters. Password length: `%s`.',
                __METHOD__,
                \htmlspecialchars(\mb_strlen($plaintext), \ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
            ));
        }
        return (string) \password_hash($plaintext, \PASSWORD_BCRYPT,
        [
            'cost' => $this->cost,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * verify().
     *
     * @param string $plaintext The plaintext to verify against hash and rehash if needed.
     * @param string $hash      The hash the plaintext should match up to.
     *
     * @return array Returns an array which contains either one or two keys, one is to tell you if the password is correct
     *               and the other one is a new hash that the old one should be replaced with.
     */
    public function verify(string $plaintext, string $hash): array
    {
        if (\mb_strlen($plaintext) > 72)
        {
            throw new LengthException(\sprintf(
                '`%s` The password is longer than 72 characters. Password length: `%s`.',
                __METHOD__,
                \htmlspecialchars(\mb_strlen($plaintext), \ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
            ));
        }
        if (\password_verify($plaintext, $hash))
        {
            $temp = $hash;
            if (\password_needs_rehash($hash, \PASSWORD_BCRYPT,
                [
                    'cost' => $this->cost,
                ])) {
                $hash = $this->cipher($plaintext);
            }
            if (!Utils::hashEquals($temp, $hash))
            {
                return (array) [
                    'password_verified' => \true,
                    'new_hash' => $hash
                ];
            }
            return (array) [
                'password_verified' => \true
            ];
        }
        return (array) [
            'password_verified' => \false
        ];
    }

}
```

The `Utils::hashEquals` is equivalent to `hash_equals()`.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php

When I construct the class into a variable and I do `$bcryptClass->cipher('Hello world!')` it shows this error below.

> Error: Call to a member function cipher() on null

There are no methods in the exceptions so it is not them.

This is the abstract class.

```
<?php

namespace Genial\Cryptography\Password;

/**
 * AbstractPasswordHash.
 */
abstract class AbstractPasswordHash
{

    /**
     * getHashInfo().
     *
     * @param string $hash The hash that will be tested.
     *
     * @return array Returns an array containing the hashing information used.
     *               It will not return the actual plaintext.
     */
    public function getHashInfo(string $hash): array
    {
        return (array) \password_get_info($hash);
    }

}
```

This is what I tested below.

```
<?php

use Genial\Cryptography\Password\Bcrypt;

$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(12);

// There has been no error yet.

echo $bcrypt->cipher('Hello world!');

// Outputs error
// Error: Call to a member function cipher() on null
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the instance of the class Bcrypt is not generated in

```
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(12)
```

because the error itself says the member function can't be called on NULL.

So, try to verify whether the new instance is created or not.